# How can I make a non-required field always show in a JIRA screen?

Tags: jira

I want to make two fields always visible on JIRA screens, but not be required.

That way I don't have to open the edit dialog to add story points, but can add/edit/read stories before they're estimated.

How can I make a non-required field always show in a JIRA screen?

Comment: Should be on-topic based on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260539/are-programming-related-web-apps-off-topic-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

You should go to `Admin>issues>Field Configuration section`. Once here you have to choose your current Scheme and open it. 
You will see a screen with all your fields. There are 3 columns, Field name,  Screens, and operations.

Go to the field you want to make visible and optional. Set the screens where you want to have it present (i assume that at least you need to add it on "View issue screen", or the custom name you gave it).

Finally make sure that at Operations column, you have correctly set it for been shown (If it allows you the "Show operation" means that it is hidden, and if it shows you "Hide" operation, means that it is gonna be shown)

On the same Field configuration screen, you can make a field Requiered or optional at operations column